# else branch of a swrl rule

Tags: protege, swrl

I want to ask if it is possible to express the else branch of a rule in SWRL?
I know it can express p->q but i want to be able to assert r if non(p)

example
HeavyPrecipitation(?x) -> hasObservationTag(?x,FalsePositiveOutlier)

and now i want to say *else hasObservationTag(?x,TruePositiveOutlier)*

How can this be done?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a rule like `(p->q)` there is no way to say `(not(p) -> ...)`; in OWL-DL+SWRL it will never be possible.

BUT, you can do things that may a be a workaround for your specific usage:

1. OWL : `ComplementOf(ClassExpression)` : work like a negation of
   the ClassExpression
2. SWRL : `DifferentIndividualsAtom(Arg1,Arg2)` : useful to exclude
   a Value or a Range

They are is the only way to express something that look like negation.

**On your example :**

```
then-rule   ClassAtom(HeavyPrecipitation,?x) -> propertyAtom(hasObservationTag,?x,FalsePositiveOutlier)

else-rule   ClassAtom(ComplementOf(HeavyPrecipitation),?x) -> propertyAtom(hasObservationTag,?x,TruePositiveOutlier)
```

Note : the negation is tricky with Open World Assumption and DL; sometime both rules (the 'then' and 'else') can be true at the same time (mainly depend on how your class are defined). Sometime none of your rules will apply : it totaly depend on how you declare classes on your individuals.